# Touching or calling setPressed() on parent View changes TextView's visibility

Tags: android, android-layout

Something very strange is going on with a custom view containing a `TextView`.  Roughly speaking, (relevant code below), I have a custom view (subclass of `FrameLayout`), which inflates some xml and adds the resulting `View` as a child.  The inflated view contains a `TextView`, referred to below as "the label".  Also possibly relevant (in case you're not going to look at the code) is that the custom view is added as a child to a `MapView`.

The following *really weird* stuff happens:

- Do nothing: label is not visible, parent looks fine. Interestingly, the parent view is clearly taking the label's width into account (with the label visibility set to `GONE` the parent view is much narrower).  In design mode the label is visible.
- Touch the parent view: Label briefly becomes visible, then disappears.  Holding your finger on it keeps the label visible until you end the touch.
- Call `this.setPressed(true)`, `this` of course being the parent view, from the parent view's constructor: Label becomes visible, and stays that way until the parent view is touched, after which behavior reverts to "normal".

Here's the relevant code.  By way of context, we're sticking a balloon on a map when you touch the map, which *should* contain something along the lines of "Tap to choose this location".  There are some other views in the balloon, but their visibility is set to `GONE` initially, and the code to fill them in and show them is disabled.  There are no map overlays involved, just attaching the view directly to the map with `MODE_MAP` to stick it to a single location.

From the custom view, BalloonView.java.  Nothing else in this class touches the layout/view methods.

```
public BalloonView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    if(!isInEditMode()){ // RoboGuice doesn't like edit mode
        RoboGuice.getInjector(context).injectMembersWithoutViews(this);
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // We're *not* attaching the view with it's default layout params.
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.balloon_view, this, false); 
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;

    addView(v,params);

    label = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);
    addressContainer = v.findViewById(R.id.addressContainer);
    address1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address1);
    address2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address2);

    // makes label visible initially
    // setPressed(true);

}

    // This is the constructor that we actually call, in case it matters...  
public BalloonView(Context context, OnClickListener onClick) {
    this(context);
    setOnClickListener(onClick);
}
```

balloon_view.xml

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip" 
        android:text="@string/map_balloon_label"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/addressContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/place" 
            android:src="@drawable/location_place" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's where we attach the `BalloonView` to the `MapView`
    private MapView.LayoutParams getBalloonViewLayoutParams(GeoPoint where){
        return new MapView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                where, MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    }

```
private void showBalloon(QPGeoPoint where) {
    latitude = where.getLatitude();
    longitude = where.getLongitude();
    BalloonView bv = getBalloonView();
    if(bv.getParent() != mapView){
        Ln.d("bv.getParent()!=mapView");
        mapView.addView(balloonView, getBalloonViewLayoutParams(where));
    }else{
        Ln.d("parent was map view");
        balloonView.setLayoutParams(getBalloonViewLayoutParams(where));
    }
    balloonView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    balloonView.setLocation(where); 
}
```

Other (possibly) relevant things:

- We're using ActionBarSherlock, RoboGuice, and the roboguice-sherlock plugin.
- The application theme is set to Sherlock.`Theme.Light.DarkActionBar`, but the activity in question has it's theme set to `Theme.DeviceDefault.NoTitleBar`.

I am completely baffled, have been trying to figure this out for hours, and will continue to do so and post updates as I find new clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ladies and gents, here it is:

The text and background were both *white*.  Touching the text set it's color state to pressed, which made it *black*.

The quick fix is to change the `textColor` attribute on the text view.

A more general fix might be to use a different theme for this activity, say, `Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoTitleBar`.

Feeling pretty dumb on this one ;P